# Mongodb não instalado

Tags: mongodb

Por algum motivo o servidor o qual trabalho desinstalou o mongodb. O banco estava com aproximadamente 200GB de dados. Se eu reinstalar o mongodb corro risco de perder os dados? Tem como eu fazer dump sem mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

Não, desde que você não apague a pasta  que esta configurada:

> ## Where and how to store data. storage:   dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb

Eu fiz isso para poder  ir da 3.2 => 4.0

Answer (score -1):

Você deu poucas informações na sua pergunta, mas com base no que está descrito:

- Você não vai perder os dados se instalar novamente o banco de dados e usar o mesmo dbpath.
- Fazer o dump você quer dizer usar mongoexport/mongodump? Se sim você precisa de um mongod executando para usar as ferramentas.

A questão é antiga mas acho que vale a documentação.